How to export Mathematica as a tex file with A4 paper format
I am trying to include my Mathematica codes as an appendix in my paper. I export the codes as a tex file to include them there. I go through:
File/Save as/example.tex
However, the exported file, example.tex, results to a too wide pdf:
I receive warnings indicating huge values of horizontal overfulls
How can I set the output page size of Mathematica to a4? If I can set the paper size to a4 from beginning in the Mathematica's worksheet, then I guess the output files (tex file in my case) would be so.
P.S.:I do prefer not to change anything by hand in the tex file. The reason is that some Mathematica answers are too wide too.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please edit the question and include a short example of the code you use to export the file, the code you use to include the file in your TeX document, and preferentially a screenshot showing the result.


How can I set the output page size of Mathematica to a4?

When you do in Mathematica   save as and select latex, Mathematica generates this
%% AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
etc....

When you compile the latex file to pdf, Latex automatically select the page size. The default happened to be A4
So there is nothing to do !
default-paper-size-is-a4-instead-of-us-letter
If you have to change the default to something other than A4, then you have to do some extra work. You can change the default paper size for pdf during installation or using other tools depending on what Latex distro you are using. I always change it myself to letter size. But if you do nothing, it will be A4.
You can also change the paper size for pdf manually to other sizes, by editing your latex document and using the geometry package. See Latex help for how to do this.  Mathematica uses the default as you can see.

If you prefer A4 with the standard european smaller margin format, you use the MaTeX package.
 Needs["MaTeX`"]
 SetOptions[MaTeX,"Preamble"-> "\\usepackage{a4wide}"]

MaTeX produces standard LaTeX layout as oposed to TeXForm, Ctrl+4 or CopyAsLatex with its annoying features, eg to produce "\r ight)" brackets  und put everything over a common denominator (MMA vs13) .
